# Wagtail PostgreSQL search backend shows warning "MyModel.search_fields contains non-existent field" yet is fully functional and operates as expected

Tags: python, django, postgresql, wagtail, wagtail-search

Hi thanks for your help in advance!

On a wagtail 2.2.2 project I recently added search functionality with PostgreSQL search backend. It was working great until I tried running a search on a filtered `PageQuerySet` by given tag whichs throws this error:

```
FilterFieldError at /blog/tags/tag_slug/

Cannot filter search results with field "tag_id". Please add index.FilterField('tag_id') to BlogPost.search_fields.

Django Version: 2.0.13
Python Version: 3.6.8

...

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/queryset.py" in search
  12.                                      operator=operator, order_by_relevance=order_by_relevance, partial_match=partial_match)

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py" in search
  371.             partial_match=partial_match,

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py" in _search
  359.         search_query.check()

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py" in check
  157.         self._get_filters_from_where_node(self.queryset.query.where, check_only=True)

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py" in _get_filters_from_where_node
  108.             child_filters = [self._get_filters_from_where_node(child) for child in where_node.children]

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py" in <listcomp>
  108.             child_filters = [self._get_filters_from_where_node(child) for child in where_node.children]

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py" in _get_filters_from_where_node
  100.             return self._process_filter(field_attname, lookup, value, check_only=check_only)

File "/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/search/backends/base.py" in _process_filter
  73.                 field_name=field_attname

Exception Type: FilterFieldError at /trust-worthy/tags/presentation/
Exception Value: Cannot filter search results with field "tag_id". Please add index.FilterField('tag_id') to BlogPost.search_fields.
```

I added the `FilterField` to the BlogPost model search_fields like it said and it seems to be working fine with correct search results returned on the filtered set. The only problem now is that every time Django boots up it shows this warning:

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
blog.BlogPost: BlogPost.search_fields contains non-existent field 'tag_id'
```

Here is a basic summary of how the relevant models are setup:

```py
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.search import index
from taggit.models import Tag, TaggedItemBase
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey


class BlogIndex(Page):

    get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)

        tag = Tag.objects.get(slug=some_tag_slug)
        pages = BlogPost.objects.descendant_of(self)\
            .live().public().order_by('-date')

        # The above <PageQuerySet> works fine to search
        # until I add this valid working filter:
        pages = pages.filter(tags=tag)

        # ...which causes the original error when searching that is
        # fixed by adding `tag_id` FilterField to BlogPost.search_fields
        pages = pages.search(some_search_query)

        # `pages` is now valid <PostgresSearchResults>
        context['pages'] = pages
        return context


class BlogPostTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('blog.BlogPost', related_name='tagged_items')


class BlogPost(Page):
    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.FilterField('tag_id'),  # This fixes the error but causes the warning
    ]
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPostTag, blank=True)
```

My question is -- what am I doing wrong to cause the warning about the non-existent field? The search works fine now on the filtered list, but it's also true that `tag_id` is not a field on the BlogPost model. Is there another proper way to fix the `Cannot filter search results` error and receive the same results?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Do you happen to have any more insights or a solution?

Comment: @JonasDrotleff I have submitted a PR to the wagtail repo that silences the warning. It is still pending review. Check it out here: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/5698

Comment: There's still no official solution right?